# Can't deploy charms due to missing metadata files

Tags: juju

I'm trying to run juju deploy from my local repository:

```
juju deploy --repository=charms local:precise/stack
```

When I do I get this message:

```
WARNING failed to load charm at "/home/eduard/charms/precise/hooks": open /home/eduard/charms/precise/hooks/metadata.yaml: no such file or directory
WARNING failed to load charm at "/home/eduard/charms/precise/hooks": open /home/eduard/charms/precise/hooks/metadata.yaml: no such file or directory
Added charm "local:precise/stack-48" to the environment.
```

The charm is running normally but I like this ad Quu not continue appearing.

I appreciate the help in advance

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have a directory in your precise directory called "hooks" Juju is trying to load this as a charm and is failing. If you remove that directory, or move it, then this warning should go away. Without knowing the structure of your stack charm, this hooks directory needs to be put in the stacks directory. The tree should be as follows:

/home/eduard/charms/precise

```
stacks/
  hooks/
    <hook files>
  metadata.yaml
  readme.md
  ... other files
```